# Makefiles with source / object files in different directories

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation

I have a project with the following directory structure:

```
         $tests/              $doc/
          |                     |-makefile 
   +------+-------+             |
   |      |       |           tests/
  test1/ test2/  test3/         |
   |      |       |       test1.rst, test2.rst, test3.rst
 test1.e test2.e test3.e
```

A file in the `$doc/tests` directory e.g `test1.rst` is created from `$tests/test1/test1.e`. I'm having problems with the makefile specifying that the source files are in `$tests/*/*.e` and the destination files are in `$doc/tests/*.rst`.

I've seen several similar questions but haven't been able to workout the correct makefile syntax.

This makefile works for a single file example

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(tests)/*/*.e)
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(doc)/tests/,$(notdir $(SOURCES:.e=.rst)))

# single file trial
SRC = $(tests)/test1/test1.e
OBJ = $(doc)/tests/test1.rst

$(OBJ): $(SRC)

debugvars:
    @echo SOURCES=$(SOURCES)
    @echo OBJECTS=$(OBJECTS)

# define how to create any RST file from a testcase
%.rst:
    $(scripts)/wr_rst.py --infile $<

# define how to create an RST file from a testcase
%.rst: %.e
    $(scripts)/wr_rst.py --infile $<

.e.rst:
    $(scripts)/wr_rst.py --infile $<

.SUFFIXES: .e .rst
```

I'm having trouble when using the full list of objects i.e.

```
all: $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)
    $(scripts)/wr_rst.py --infile $<
```

`test1.rst` is generated 3 times and `test2,3.rst` are ignored. The `$(SOURCES)` and `$(OBJECTS)` are correct. I suspect that `$<` does not iterate over the `(SOURCES)`

Here is some of the output from `make -d`

```
     No implicit rule found for `$tests/test3/test3.e'.                                   
 Finished prerequisites of target file `$tests/test3/test3.e'.                        
No need to remake target `$tests/test3/test3.e'.                                      
Considering target file `tests/test3.rst'.
 File `tests/test3.rst' does not exist.
  Pruning file `$tests/test1/test1.e'.
  Pruning file `$tests/test2/test2.e'.
  Pruning file `$tests/test3/test3.e'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `tests/test3.rst'.
Must remake target `tests/test3.rst'.
$scripts/wr_rst.py --inile $tests/test1/test1.e
Putting child 0x00ee6420 (tests/test3.rst) PID 11720 on the chain.
Live child 0x00ee6420 (tests/test3.rst) PID 11720
Writing RST file $doc/tests/test1.rst
Reaping winning child 0x00ee6420 PID 11720
Removing child 0x00ee6420 PID 11720 from chain.
Successfully remade target file `tests/test3.rst'.
```

Comment: Indeed, [`$<` expands to the first prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), which in this case is `$(tests).test1.test1.e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This question looks very familiar-- I'd almost swear that one essentially the same has been asked and answered.)

Let's take this in stages. We could write the rules one at a time:

```
$(doc)/tests/test1.rst: $(tests)/test1/test1.e
    ...
```

but that's tedious. It's the kind of situation that cries out for a wildcard solution, such as a pattern rule, but one of Make's serious shortcomings is its crude handling of wildcards. A pattern rule in which the wildcard is repeated:

```
$(doc)/tests/%.rst: $(tests)/%/%.e
    ...
```

is not allowed. But we could write the rules using `eval`:

```
define template
$(doc)/tests/$(1).rst: $(tests)/$(1)/$(1).e
    use some tool to build $$@ from $$<
endef

$(eval $(call template,test1))
$(eval $(call template,test2))
...
```

Then instead of writing all of those `eval` statements, we can delegate that job to `foreach`:

```
TESTS := test1 test2 ...

$(foreach TEST,$(TESTS),$(eval $(call template,$(TEST)))
```

Then instead of writing that list of tests, we can delegate that to `wildcard`, and use the same list to construct a list of target files:

```
TESTS := $(notdir $(wildcard $(tests)/*))
TARGETS := $(patsubst %,$(doc)/tests/%.rst,$(TESTS))

all: $(TARGETS)
```

Putting all of these together is straightforward, but this answer is getting long.

Comment: Thanks Beta this works perfectly. For my education there's no way to create a new rule such that for any target .rst file, make launches a script on the e source with the same name, regardless of source / destination directories.
    `.e.rst:
         $(scripts)/wr_rst.py --infile $<`